How to fills my container with my cards? (Flex)
i'm new to html and i want to create cards which fills the container.


.services-container {
    display: flex;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.services-card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
<div class="services-container">
   <div class="services-card">
     <h3>Services 1</h3>
     <p>Services Information</p>
   </div>
   <div class="services-card">
     <h3>Services 2</h3>
     <p>Services Information</p>
   </div>
   <div class="services-card">
     <h3>Services 3</h3>
     <p>Services Information</p>
   </div>
   <div class="services-card">
     <h3>Services 4</h3>
     <p>Services Information</p>
   </div>
   <div class="services-card">
     <h3>Services 5</h3>
     <p>Services Information</p>
   </div>
<!--and more services-->
</div>



It turned out broken like this image:

If someone can help me and provide learning resources it would be appreciated, thanks.
Cards filling the container without it overflowing out of device width

You are missing a " in your first .services-container class I am correcting it in snippet so should work fine

I just checked you code.
It is working fine.
you were missing closing " for the class of services-container

First of all, your code is missing a double quotes in the first class "services-container".
Besides that, I don't know if I exactly get your point, but if you want to fill the entire container with all the services, you can just add width: 100% to your CSS. Just like that:
.services-card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}

